# subquery in sybase Create table clause

Tags: oracle, subquery, sybase, database-migration, sql-delete

I have multiple Oracle queries that I want to transform to Sybase language. Since Am new to Sybase i was wondering if we can insert subquery in "create clause" or in "delete clause" in sybase ?

```
create table LIQ_PURGE_AK as select M_REFERENCE from LPOS_AK_DBF where M_PRIC_TYPE in (2, 3)

select distinct M_PROD_OREF from LPOS_DTL_DBF where M_REFERENCE in (select M_OBJ_DETAIL from LPOS_LQE_DBF where M_AK_CLASS = 'MEqGp44051' and M_AK_REF in (select M_REFERENCE from LIQ_PURGE_AK3)) 


delete from LPOS_DTL_DBF where M_REFERENCE in (select M_OBJ_DETAIL from LPOS_LQE_DBF where M_AK_CLASS = 'MEqGp44051' and M_AK_REF in (select M_REFERENCE from LIQ_PURGE_AK3))
```

Comment: What happens when you run your query in Sybase?

Comment: I Can't run the queries since the DB is at the customers side and these are delete/create queries which will change the customers data but does this syntax works on Sybase ? @BobJarvis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this case:

```
create table LIQ_PURGE_AK as select M_REFERENCE from LPOS_AK_DBF where M_PRIC_TYPE in (2, 3)
```

you could change to:

```
select M_REFERENCE into LIQ_PURGE_AK from LPOS_AK_DBF where M_PRIC_TYPE in (2, 3)
```

all other case you could leave "AS IS". You could be free with subquery in the delete clause (but could be exceptions with a **group by**)

Answer (score 0):

Remark #1: I'm assuming you're talking about Sybase ASE here (the SQL dialect for Sybase IQ and Sybase SQL Anywhere is different). To let folks help you, always specify the product you're using and the actual version. "Sybase" is not a database , but a family of databases with many differences between them.

Raemark #2: there's only one good way to solve such issues, and that is to try and run it. You can (and should) download one of the free versions of ASE to try these things out. See www.sypron.nl/ase_free

Remark #3: The CREATE TABLE...SELECT syntax is not valid in ASE. You can however do SELECT-INTO, which creates the table (unlike the SELECT-INTO in other SQL dialects which assigns retrieved values to variables). Look up the SELECT-INTO syntax in the ASE documentation at http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.help.ase.15.7.sp100/doc/html/title.html (note that the name Sybase has been formally dropped, but that doesn't matter for all intents and purposes)